# For spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer which one is recommended ActiveMQConnectionFactory or ActiveMQ PooledConnectionFactory?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

As per the javadoc of [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html)

> Note: Don't use Spring's CachingConnectionFactory in combination with dynamic scaling. Ideally, don't use it with a message listener container at all, since it is generally preferable to let the listener container itself handle appropriate caching within its lifecycle. Also, stopping and restarting a listener container will only work with an independent, locally cached Connection - not with an externally cached one.

What I understand from this note is that I should use *ConnectionFactory* directly from the *vendor*.

So my question is the following:

Which *ConnetionFactory* from *ActiveMQ* is efficent to use with *Spring*'s *DefaultMessageListenerContainer*:

*org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory* **or**
*org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory* **?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pooled connection factory is ok but generally unnecessary because DMLC connections are long-lived.

A Spring `SingleConnectionFactory` might be better because all the consumers will share a single connection (it is the parent of the `CachingConnectionFactory`).

The note in the javadocs stems from issues with caching consumers, not the use of the single connection.

Caches/Pools are generally needed when sessions/connections are short-lived (e.g. when performing `JmsTemplate` operations).

If you are using transactions and you want to perform `JmsTemplate` operations on the listener's session, you must configure the `JmsTemplate` to use the same connection factory as the DMLC.